# @focus event is not bubble by default

Tags: events, vuejs3

Vue version:
3.2.39

While click on the button, the focus does not bubble to the wrapper, and that is why it does not show the "wrapper focus". How to fix this?

```
<template>
  <div tabindex="-1" @focus="onWrapperFocus" @blur="onWrapperBlur">
    <button @focus="onInnerFocus" @blur="onInnerBlur">Hello</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script >
export default {
  setup() {
    return {
      onWrapperFocus() {
        console.log("wrapper focus");
      },

      onWrapperBlur() {
        console.log("wrapper blur");
      },

      onInnerFocus() {
        console.log("inner focus");
      },

      onInnerBlur() {
        console.log("inner blur");
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Expected behavior:

```
inner focus 
wrapper focus
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turned out, this is not related to vue.  Just needs to read the documentation time to time. About focusin/focusout -
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusin_event

Instead focus/blur, I use focusin/focusout and it's work how I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

There is another phase of event called "capturing". It is rarely used in real code, but can be usefull in this case.

You can add the capturing phase by adding `.capture` after the event name like shown below:

```html
<div tabindex="-1" @focus.capture="onWrapperFocus" @blur.capture="onWrapperBlur">
  <button @focus="onInnerFocus" @blur="onInnerBlur">Hello</button>
</div>
```